# Finding the correct position of a scaled element (added diagram)

Tags: c, math, drawing, coordinates, scale

Very complicated for me to explain the problem, but I will try my best.

I am making a game. There is an area of game objects and a canvas that draws every object in that area using some "draw_from" function - `void draw_from(const char *obj, int x, int y, double scale)` so that it looks as if a copy of that area is made on-screen.

This gives the advantage of scaling that area using the `scale` parameter of the `draw_from()` function.

However, a problem occurs when doing so. For simplicity imagine there are just two actors in that area - one that is right above the other one.
When they are scaled-down, they will appear in different vertical positions, further from each other.

I need to calculate the new correct positions for each of the objects and pass them to `draw_from`, but I just seem to be unable to figure out how. What is the correct way to recalculate the new positions if each of those objects is scaled down with the same value?

---

Here is a decent illustration of the problem more or less:

[image]

As you can tell the `draw_from` function will draw the object centered on the x/y coordinates. To draw an object at `0:0` (top-left corner) you must do `draw_from(obj, obj->width/2, obj->height/2, 1.0);` Not sure if the scaling is implemented that way exactly, but I created a function to obtain the new width and height of the scaled object:

```
void character_draw_get_scaled_dimensions (Actor* srcActor, double scale, double* sWidth, double* sHeight)
{
    double sCharacterWidth = 0;
    double sCharacterHeight = 0;

    if(srcActor->width >= srcActor->height)
    {
        sCharacterWidth = (double)srcActor->width * scale / 1.0;
        sCharacterHeight = sCharacterWidth * (double)srcActor->height / (double)srcActor->width;
    }
    else
    {
        sCharacterHeight = (double)srcActor->height * scale / 1.0;
        sCharacterWidth = sCharacterHeight * (double)srcActor->width / (double)srcActor->height;
    }

    if(sWidth)
        (*sWidth) = sCharacterWidth;
    if(sHeight)
        (*sHeight) = sCharacterHeight;
}
```

In other words, I need to maintain the distances between those objects across down-scales and I explained how `draw_from` and /somehow/ how its scaling works.
I need the correct parameters to pass to the `draw_from`'s x and y arguments.
From that point, I think it will get just too broad if I continue elaborating further.

Comment: It might help to step away from the source code and get the math correct first. You need to scale not only width and height but also the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Not the solution I hoped for, but it is still a solution.
The more hacky and less practical (including performance-wise) solution is to draw every object on an offscreen canvas with a scale of 1.0 then draw from that canvas to the main canvas at any scale desired.

That way only the canvas should be repositioned and not every object. It gets really easy from there. I still would prefer the conventional purposed mathematical solution.